# How do I keep a page from reloading when navigated away from

Tags: html

I have a chrome kiosk application with a handful of pages. I would like to keep these pages from reloading when they are navigated to and away from so that any data that is changed does not reset. As an example, one of the pages is a chalkboard where you can leave notes, however, whenever the page is revisited, it is refreshed and the notes are no longer there.

I have tried both buttons and href's...

```
<a href="kitchenmessages.html"><div id="messageshome"><h1>ChalkBoard</h1>    </div></button>

<button onclick="window.location.href='kitchenmessages.html'"><div id="messageshome"><h1>ChalkBoard</h1></div></button>
```

Comment: You can't do this sort of thing with HTML markup or JavaScript. Those are volatile storage mechanisms. Look at cookies, local browser storage, or a back-end (server/database) solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should store the data in some kind of database, so when you go back to a certain page you can retrieve that data from it.
Another way is using javascript, though that wouldn't make your changes permanent.